# Text editor for CMS

Tags: php

I have a website and I have created the CMS for it using PHP and mySQL.
When I edit the content with the CMS I am actually editing the content stored inside mySQL then, using PHP, the content is displayed back to the site by reading the updated content from mySQL.

Now I am looking for a text editor to use inside my CMS to format the text and display the "formated" text on my site.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: will SQL deformat the text though? because my data is stored in mySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most popular and easiest editor to use is TinyMCE available at:

http://www.tinymce.com/

Another few editors i know of but don't use anymore are:

1. FCKEditor (Maybe the same as CKEditor that Shyiu proposed)
2. Xinha Open Source Editor

I recommend TinyMCE for it's flexibility, speed and ease of use compbined with JQuery support.

Good luck

Comment: will there be a problem installing as I am using mySQL to retrieve data to my site

Comment: These tools are database and most of the time language agnostic, they expect you to output the data inside a DIV or a TEXTAREA and they'll change the DIV or TEXTAREA into a full fledge editor... Just lookup the documentation they are usually pretty straightforward to install...

Comment: FCK is now known as CK.  There won't be any problems with mysql integration.  Just output your field in the textarea like this:  `<textarea name="content"><?php echo $your_data; ?></textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

I have used CKEditor in one of the projects i worked and i worked fine for me

http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: thank you for your answer Shyju...will mySQL remove all formatting though?

Comment: adrian : mysql wont remove formating if u store the value in a varchar field.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [WMD editor](https://github.com/openlibrary/wmd)